# 複数項目が入っているListViewから任意の項目だけを取り出したい

Tags: android, java

Androidアプリを作っているのですが自分でカスタムしたListViewから任意の場所の任意の項目だけを取り出す方法がわからず困っています。

***item.xml***

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/relation_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
    <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
```

***MainActivityの一部***

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getReadableDatabase();

        ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //DBを取得
        cursor=db.query("persons",null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        listView1.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.item,cursor,new String[]{
                "_id","name","relation","date","place"},new int[]{R.id.id_item,R.id.name_item,R.id.relation,R.id.date_item,R.id.place_item},0));

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

            }

        });

    }
```

ここでListViewがクリックされた際にR.id.id_itemに入っている内容を取り出し、変数に代入したいのですが任意のpositionのListView内のTextViewの内容を取り出す方法が分かりません。どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。
これまではposisionの位置にcursor.moveToPosition(position)で移動していたのですがこれだとListViewを並び替えた際に使えないことがわかってしまい困っています。

Answer (score 1):

Cursorで項目を取り出すのために`cursor.getColumnIndex("name")`を使います：

```
String currentId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
String currentName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
```

例えば：

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String currentId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String currentName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        Log.v(TAG, "クリックid/name は : " + currentId + " => " + currentName);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

もし、click された item の TextView から取得するのが良いということでしたら、
`onItemClick()` の引数 `view` にその item の view が渡されてきていますので、

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_item);
String text = (String) textView.getText();
```

でいかがでしょうか。